# MCP23017 to control a relay board failing when 6 or more relays are active

Tags: relay

I'm having a problem with a circuit I'm building.

I have connected a MCP23017 to a Odroid C1 via I2C with a level converter. And the MCP23017 is connected to a 8 channel relay board.

The thing is that if I activate each channel independently it works just fine, I put a timer to set 1 on 1 on and off and it works.

But if I do the same thing without setting off the previous one, after a random time it start to turn on and off relays that are not correct, it's like the MCP23017 goes crazy, so if I restart the application it will work fine again until the same happens.

It's like when the relay board is consuming more power the MCP23017 goes crazy..
I tried putting a 47uF capacitor in the MCP23017 VDD-GND pins but it didn't fix it.

Any ideas in what can be causing the issue?

Thanks.

Edit:
@Mike I'm using this relay board:
[image]
This Odroid C1
This level converter to match de 3v3 I2C on the Odroid with the 5V on the MCP23017: Image in comments I cant attach anymore
I'm using an external power reguled to 5V by this: Image in comments I cant attach anymore

And of course the MCP23017.

I have connected the GPB pins of the MCP23017 to the pins in the Relay board.

Here is the PCB I built for this: [image: pcb]
It has a lot of other components, but the one I'm trying to use now is the MCP23017-1, Relay-board 1, Level-Converter, DC-Regulator, and the Odroid connector.

The idea is to control multiples things with this. But I'm having trouble with the relay board in that way.

If the sequence is with one on one, it works without a glitch, if I start turning on a few at a time it goes crazy.

The relay board works with GND on the channels, so if I set the pin to 1 it turns off, if I set it to 0 it turns on.

Comment: Please post a schematic.
Also provide more detail about the relay board, does it include drivers ?

Comment: What value pull-up do you have on the I2C bus and how long is it? What drives the I2C bus?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hntT.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz1L7.jpg

Comment: No, I'm not going to look up what a MCP23017 is just to answer a question here.

Comment: A schematic would be much more useful than the PCB layout. A photograph of the relay board is not very useful either. Its documentation would be more relevant, and showing how you connected it even more. You also provided yet another picture of an assembled board in the comments above, but we don't even know what it relates to. This is messy.

Comment: I don't have a schematic for this, I build the PCB directly as I use all prebuilt componets.. If you can't understand it that way I will try to make the schematic later but it's all built with those componets I put before, there is no extra resistors or anything.
It's my first try to build something like this. So if I have to rebuild the PCB and add some extra things it won't be an issue. But I don't have much experience in this and I don't know what the problem can be.

The I2C bus with handle 4 MCP23017 and 1 Arduino Nano in slave mode. Should I add resistors in the middle?

Comment: I think this is probably part of the explanation, then. Building a circuit that you don't have the schematic for, and that you don't really know how it works easily leads to mistakes, and you can't troubleshoot since, once again, you don't know how it works. And we can't really help you find out the root cause, in that case. Take the time to understand the circuit, first. If there are things you don't understand, ask here (with a proper schematic). After this, you'll be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: Post links to the datasheets of the parts used not just photos of them, that is completely useless.

Comment: How do you have a PCB you have built for this but no schematic of that PCB?

Comment: I built the PCB with EasyEDA, and you can make the PCB directly without schematics. This didn't allowed me to put more than 2 links.. that's why I didn't put all the datasheets.

MCP23017: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf
Level converter: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BSS138.pdf

DC Regulator: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf

Odroid C1: http://dn.odroid.com/homebackup/odroid-c_rev0.3_201401107.pdf

Relay board: http://www.sainsmart.com/zen/documents/20-018-904/8%20solid%20relay.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries I found the problem.

It seems that a 10k resistor has to be place in the !RESET pin. So I put the resistor there and know it behaves as it shoulds.

Thanks!